# How does the Millenials' support for Corbyn square off with the anti-Brexit stance of most young people in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, demographics, labour-party, jeremy-corbyn

[According to Yougov](https://yougov.co.uk/topics/politics/explore/public_figure/Jeremy_Corbyn), among Millennials, Corbyn is the most popular politician in the UK (although he fares far worse among other age groups).

[image]

At the same time, the youth [is the most anti-Brexit/pro-Remain](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-45098550) segment of the population.

[image]

Given Corbyn's [own Eurosceptic views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Jeremy_Corbyn#European_Union), how does one explain this apparent contradiction?

Answer (score 9):

Beyond the obvious (and possibly true) comments to be made about idealists with less exposure to the realities of life, and the general truism that voters in general seem to be more tribal than logical, the fact is that you can support a candidate despite him having one policy you disagree with if you believe that his or her package as a whole is the best. Presumably for many of these this appeals as a package, even with the drawback of Euroscepticism.

There is a further point that labour have gone to great lengths to avoid having any real discernable policy at all on Brexit, and this would allow people to believe that when push comes to shove it will be the cautious approach that would be taken (i.e no Brexit) especially with the latest official position (as of this post being written).

Comment: Just to add, but in a comment as perhaps unfair in the answer, as the group seeing themselves  promised the most free stuff by Corbyn, if their anti-brexit position stems from pure self -interest maybe the Corbyn + Brexit is an overall better propesition from the self interest pov

Comment: I think it is a flaw in the UK's political system, but especially in a single issue instance it never matters what the opposition's policy is, because their influence on policy is negligible. The Labour party have had Brexit policy on different parts of the negotiations, but without the chance to push this into the EU negotiations, which have been conducted by the Conservative party. Honestly, when their influence into a give and take scenario is roughly the same as the general public, how is their stance supposed to be expressed?

Comment: They have to react to how the EU responds to proposals they would never have put forward. How is that supposed to end up 'discernable'?

Comment: @Jontia the same way that policies are always expressed. What we've had form labour is 'we're for/against Brexit, a second vote, a deal, revoking, depending on who you ask in the party; the one thing that we're sure about is we oppose whatever the Tories are doing, even if it's what we want' they even at one point said they'd negotiate a deal, and campaign against that deal in a confirmatory referendum

Comment: The last part of that is straight out of the Daily Mail. The whole reason for Labour not having a constant stance is because the ground underneath them is shifted by the current Conservative/EU negotiations. Labour will campaign against their own 'deal' if it turns out relations have been poisoned enough that they can't get the deal they believe they could have got if they'd been in charge from the start. That makes sense; if someone hands you a ruined relationship, riding it down in  flames is just foolish. The 'campaign against their own deal' argument is reduction to absurdity.

Comment: @Jontia enough of your slurs: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/uk-politics-49605019/thornberry-on-brexit-i-d-negotiate-a-deal-but-campaign-against-it

Comment: That's one person, not labour policy. Let's not forget who the Foreign Secretary was during the first 18 months of Brexit negotiations.

Comment: @Jontia as I said in that comment there is no clear labour policy, and it seems different depending on who you ask, in this case the shadow foreign secretary. From the second part of your comment you seem to be suffering from the mistaken belief that I have anything other than contempt for Boris Johnson or the way Brexit has been handled by the Conservatives; perhaps me not dragging them into a question about labour confused you?

Comment: I am merely trying to point out how difficult it is to have a clear policy when the starting point keeps shifting. But you're right it probably is off on a tangent from the original question.

Comment: I don't agree that "there is no clear Labour party policy" ON Brexit. There is one,  it's just a lot more nuanced than anyone else's. This is an artefact of the situation they find themselves in vis a vis the opinions of Labour voters; unlike most of the other parties they have a hefty split in opinion and so it's dangerous for them to be seen to alienate one side entirely. Frankly, given their situation, I think they're actually doing quite well with their policy drafting,  I don't see what else they could possibly have done.